# How to do color-fill in images in Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, color, filling

`Color fill`, the ability to apply a desired color to an enclosed area,  is one of the basic functions provided by most graphic applications. Is there a similar function provided in Mathematica? For example, how to obtain a *red*, *green*, *blue* and *yellow* horses silhouette from the [picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeYq.jpg) in *Mathematica*?

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeYq.jpg"]
ReplacePixelValue[im, {924, 221} -> Blue]
```

`ReplacePixelValue` seems only work on one pixel only.

`Colorize` seems provide no controls on obtaining a specific color.

`ColorReplace` seems only work on a bundle of the same color all together .

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
im = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeYq.jpg"];
Colorize[MorphologicalComponents@im, 
          ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Yellow, 3 -> Blue, 4 -> Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems there is a strange behaviour behind  `MorphologicalComponents`, So I raised another [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59400/why-colorreplace-does-not-follow-the-rules-specified) about it.

Comment: Is this method only good for binarized pictures?

Comment: @Putterboy Not at all: `MorphologicalComponents[image,t]
treats values above t as foreground.`