# Why ColorReplace does not follow the rules specified?

Tags: image-processing

I tried to use `ColorReplace` to change the colors obtained from `MorphologicalComponents`. However some of the changes didn't follow the rules specified, Is there any reasons?

```
im2 = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeYq.jpg"];
im3 = Colorize@ MorphologicalComponents@im2 
colors = DominantColors[im3, 5]
```

[image]

Now trying to change the colors accordingly,

```
ColorReplace[im3, {
  colors[[2]] -> Red, 
  colors[[3]] -> Blue, 
  colors[[4]] -> Green, 
  colors[[5]] -> Yellow
  }]
```

One of the changes did not follow the rules specified:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default tolerance (distance) of [`ColorReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorReplace.html) is such that first and third horses are considered similar:

[image]

```
ColorReplace[im3, colors[[2]] -> Red]
```

[image]

Use a smaller value for the distance parameter:

```
ColorReplace[im3, {
  colors[[2]] -> Red, 
  colors[[3]] -> Blue, 
  colors[[4]] -> Green, 
  colors[[5]] -> Yellow
  },
  0.01
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do can be done way easier:

```
i = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDeYq.jpg"];
Colorize[MorphologicalComponents@i, 
 ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Yellow}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is that the color order different from the rule your specified?

Comment: The colors are in the order I specified. Keep in mind that the ordering depends on the order of components provided by `MorphologicalComponents`